# Access at type under module

Tags: ocaml

i explain u my problem

I have an module like this :

a.ml

```
module A = struct 
type t = int * int
end
```

a.mli

```
module A :sig
type t = int * int
end
```

main.ml

```
let test = A.t(8, 9)
```

How can i solved this error :

```
Error: Unbound value A.t
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have this error too : Error: Unbound constructor

Comment: Solved thx at community

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Comment: open "a.ml" in main.ml but i have new problem if i try too use directly the type like this A.t, i have same error

Comment: Files are already modules named by their filename. In this case it's redundent to create an additional module around `t` in `a.ml` and `a.mli`. Then, you can leave out the `open A`.

Answer (score 0):

`A.t` is a type, and therefore `A.t (8,9)` makes little sense. This has nothing to do with modules, you would have obtained the same with:

```
# type t = int*int;;
type t = int * int
# t (1,2);;
Error: Unbound value t
```